# Low-frequency response of a CS amplifier

Tags: mosfet, high-frequency

I would like to ask for the sentece below in the the red box  if fp2=400Hz, fp2=100Hz and fp1=60Hz then I can assume that fL=fp2=400Hz? And the other case  if fp2=300Hz, fp2=100Hz and fp1=60Hz then fL=fp1+fp2+fp3=460Hz?

I ask this because I saw a problem where fp2=500Hz, fp2=100Hz and fp1=60Hz and  calculate that fL=fp1+fp2+fp3=660Hz.This is correct?I think from the theory below should give us fL=500Hz.

[image]

Comment: The geometric mean give us better approximation then simply numerically add. $$F_L\approx \sqrt{F1^2 + F2^2 + F3^2}$$ http://leachlegacy.ece.gatech.edu/ece3050/notes/bjt/cefreqrev.pdf and you can find this equation in  Sendra-Smith book.https://www.ittfedifermi.gov.it/progetti/englishintechnology/lessons/lesson%201/unit.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement below the red boxed text is fundamentally wrong because you cannot simply numerically add the frequencies of several cascaded filters and produce a number that has any accurate meaning. There might be some particular cases where it has some semi coincidental accuracy but these situations are not obvious and it would be naive to assume it will work. Given the usage of free sim tools I would advise against using this formula in favour of performing a simulation.

Comment: Andy aka thank for your answer.This statement exists and in Sendra-Smith book .Maybe is correct for only one or two stages amplifiers?

Comment: I've edited my answer since you first read it.